# How to pass data into swiftui view and access it

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swift-structs

Im trying to pass data into a swiftui view to be displayed when it is initialized, but am having trouble getting it to work.

Here is my code which passes data into my 'MarkerInfoWindow.swift' view:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    print("Showing marker infowindow")
    print("marker.userData: \(marker.userData)")
    let mUserData = marker.userData as? [String:String]
    print("mUserData?['name']", (mUserData?["name"]) ?? "mUserData[name] was nil")

    let mInfoWindow = UIHostingController(rootView: MarkerInfoWindow(placedata: mUserData!))

    return mInfoWindow.view
}
```

Here is the code to my 'MarkerInfoWindow.swift' view:

```
struct PlaceDataStruct {
    var name : String
    var place_id : String
}


struct MarkerInfoWindow: View {

    var placedata: [PlaceDataStruct]  

    var body: some View {

        //Here is where i keep getting errors regardless if i use this method or dot notation
        Text(placedata["name"])

    }
}
```

Im not sure if im implementing my PlaceDataStruct incorrectly. 
**Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, so that I can display the right data every time my view is initialized?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re `MarkerInfoWindow` is expecting an array of structs but the data you are passing is a dictionary, in the form `[String: String]`

You should update your `MarkerInfoWindow` to accept a dictionary instead. Here is an example of how to do that.

```
struct MarkerInfoWindow: View {

    var placedata: [String: String]  // update to be dictionary

    var body: some View {

        Text(placedata["name", default: ""]) // use correct notation for accessing dictionary

     }
 }
```

You’re also force unwrapping the data before you pass it to your `MarkerInfoWindow` if that’s your intention that is ok. But note that if your data isn’t there then it will crash your app.